# Как работает присваивание элементам значения в массиве Java?

Tags: java, массивы

Столкнулся с интересным синтаксисом. Как работает выделенная строка?

```
public class Test {
    public static int[] getArray() {
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int index = 1;
        try {
            getArray()[index = 2]++; //эта строка
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }//empty catch       
        System.out.println("index = " + index);
    }
}
```

> sout: index = 2

Ссылка на похожую тему [на иностранном SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263673/need-help-understanding-strange-array-syntax)

Comment: Вначале переменной `index` присваивается 2, потом полученный результат используется в качестве индекса. И если бы `getArray()` возвращал вменяемый массив, мы бы получили его 2-ой элемент и увеличили бы этот элемент на 1 (++).

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець почему присваивание работает в массив?

Comment: Не понял вопрос. Присваивается в данном случае значение 2 переменной `index`

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець в чём практическая полезность такого синтаксиса `...[index = 2]++` ?

Comment: Кроме записи в одну строку никакой "полезности" тут нет. Просто надо научиться читать код, как его читает компилятор, и все станет понятнее. Все дело в последовательности исполнения выражений, в данном случае он не тупо слева-направо.

Comment: Оператор присваивания является выражением, результат этого выражения - значение переменной после присваивания (At run time, the result of the assignment expression is the value of the variable after the assignment has occurred. [jls-15.26](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае код

```
getArray()[index = 2]++;
```

аналогичен коду

```
index = 2;
getArray()[index]++;
```

А потом в конце у вас выводится в консоль index, которые равен двум. Массив тут не при чем, тем более что он null, если уберете блок try-catch, то приложение будет падать с исключением NullPointerException.

Comment: Почему такая конструкция ...[index = 2]++ заложена? Зачем необходимо такое присваивание внутри скобок?

Comment: @KeyJibo, ни скобки, ни массив тут совсме ни причем. Просто несколько операторов в одной строке, которые в данном случае выполняются в определенном порядке.

Comment: @KeyJibo вам нужно просто знать, что так делать можно. И нужно понимать, в каком порядке отработает код, написанный подобным образом. Зачем - вопрос другой. Возможно, в реализации какого-то приложения в такой конструкции будет смысл. Как минимум, чтобы сэкономить одну строку кода.

Comment: Спасибо, я понял.